# How to use Google Transliterate API in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api

I want to implement Google Transliterate api in ios. Its transliterate not translate.This is the google Transliterate api link https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started . That api is javascripts api, how can i use it in ios?
Transliterate mean if i write a word in arabic language i need to convert that arabic word in english letter not english word.

Comment: Do your research before asking questions. First hit on Google: https://github.com/gpolak/FGTranslator

Comment: I already searched but did not find about ios. FGTranslator is only a translator but i need Transliterate mean if i write a text in arabic language it gives me output on english letter. @Swinny89